# Cannot delete S3 object, "Access Denied"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to delete an object through the REST API and getting an `AccessDenied` 403.

My bucket policy is as follows:

```
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Id": "<redacted>",
     "Statement": [
         {
             "Sid": "<redacted>",
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Principal": {
                 "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<redacted>:user/ts-user"
             },
             "Action": [
                 "s3:PutObject",
                 "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                 "s3:GetObject",
                 "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                 "s3:DeleteObject"
             ],
             "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<redacted>/*"
         }
     ]
}
```

The weird thing is that if I change my Principle to `"*"` (public), the DELETE works.

The user `ts-user` has the policy `AmazonS3FullAccess` attached and so does the group it belongs to. I have also tried using the credentials of the root user who is also the bucket owner.

I can see that the bucket policy file is being read from because if I remove the `PutObject` permissions I can no longer upload files. But I don't understand what else is needed so that I can delete files I have uploaded.

The files are being uploaded with `public-read` ACL but I have also tried `bucket-owner-full-control`.

Been stuck for hours and not sure what else to try!

Comment: 1) Why are you using bucket policies to mix with IAM policies? Use IAM policies. 2) Using the credentials for `ts-user` run `aws iam get-user`. Does the ARN for the user ID match your bucket policy? 3) Unless required, don't use `public-read` as your testing case. I have seen lots of accidents in the real world.

Comment: OK so I removed the bucket policy (now just using IAM policy- `AmazonS3FullAccess` on the user). I also added `AdministratorAccess` so I could run `get-user` and the ARN does match what was in the bucket policy before I deleted it. I can still upload but not delete.

Comment: For the files that you cannot delete, double check the object ownership and ACL.

Comment: The object is owned by the root account, but I have tried using my root credentials to delete with no success. I can delete from the AW console using my `ts-user` account. The ACL is `public-read`.

Comment: I don't know the answer. It is very strange that you cannot delete using root credentials. Is there some history to these files that you are leaving out. Such as copied from another account, encrypted, any idea?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've been going through the auth header generation code with a fine tooth comb all day making sure the sig generation is correct and ony just realised my HTTP networking library strips the `Authorization` header before sending over the wire... D'oh. Closing question as that is undoubtably the issue.